# How can I differentiate between users with lookup

Tags: python, django, one-to-one

I have two classes `Customer` and `Restaurant` that have `OneToOneField` with the django built in `User`. When I go to a page I am trying to determine which `User` it is. What I am doing doesnt work because the `User` model will always return True for having a `restaurant` attribute, so it never makes it past the first `if` statement...

models.py

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    restaurant_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    restaurant_name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    if User.restaurant:
        return render(request,'usermanage/dashboard_restaurant.html')
    elif User.customer is not None:
        return redirect(request, 'usermanage/dashboard.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'usermanage/dashboard.html')
```

Comment: You should set a flag or status field or role field which describes which type of user, in your `CustomUser` model. Then, you can differentiate between the two without any complications. Without that, Django has no way distinguishing between a Restaurant user and a Customer user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view file is checking the `restaurant` attribute on the `User` model and not the instance, this is not how you use Models in Django, please read the documentation on [Django's ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/) for the correct usage.  You can access the authenticated user from the request with `request.user`.  You should do something like:

```
def dashboard(request):
    user = request.user
    if user and hasattr(user, 'restaurant'):
        return render(request,'usermanage/dashboard_restaurant.html')
    elif user and hasattr(user, 'customer') is not None:
        return redirect(request, 'usermanage/dashboard.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'usermanage/dashboard.html')
```

Make sure you read the documentation on Django's OneToOneField and ORM.  If you refer to the [One-to-one relationship documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships) you would read:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist  
try:  
    p2.restaurant  
except ObjectDoesNotExist:  
    print("There is no restaurant here.")
```

> There is no restaurant here.

You can also use hasattr to avoid the need for exception catching:

```
hasattr(p2, 'restaurant')
```

> False

One of these two example should be how you check for the missing `restaurant` on your user.

Comment: i was trying request.user for a while with no luck. I am still getting an error with this method: `Exception Value: User has no restaurant.`